# Adding line seperator to right click menu of a Memory Stick

Tags: autorun, memorystick, context-menu

i'm creating an autorun.inf file for one of my memory sticks, i want to stick a bunch of commonly used programs on it using the `shell\` syntax but when i create them they sit under Autoplay

what i really want to do it create that Line separator that's underneath Autoplay to separate my stuff, like how Cut and Copy, Create Shortcut and Rename, and Properties are separated

---

here's what i have planned for the menu

```
Autorun
----------------------------
Open Kia
Sync Kia (To C.C)
Sync Kia (To Aura)
Current Project Listing
Owner Information
----------------------------
Sharing and Security
```

ideally i would want the Sync Kia ones to be in a separate menu named Sync Kia and when you hover over them you have the next menu open with the option C.C and Aura

I'm currently building this autorun.inf file in Windows XP and will mainly be used for it but i would like it to be compatible with Windows 7

Kia is the name of my Memory Stick, Aura is the name of my Laptop with Windows XP and C.C is the name of my main Computer with Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you already reading this MSDN article ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It might be worth trying to define the versions of Windows you're using since older versions react differently to autorun commands

Have you picked the commands you want to menu yet or were your examples the commands you plan using, cause I have ideas of maybe just batch commands using relative paths "..COMMANDHERE /flags -options" that might be in batch scripts launched from autorun.inf when some commands aren't possible.

Autorun has evolved in the history of MS and there are some magical things but some frustrating limits to, just depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: strange how that link didn't show up when i did a google search, refer to the edit i have made to my question about my planned menu and versions of windows